# How do I toggle soft-wrapped lines in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, wrapping, line-truncation

I want to be able to toggle soft-wrapped lines in org-mode. My `.emacs` file has this code:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Org Mode ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)

;; Start-up with soft-wrap enabled
(setq org-startup-truncated nil)  ; This works
;; Toggle soft-wrap with super-q
(define-key org-mode-map "s-q" 'toggle-truncate-lines)  ; This doesn't
```

I would like to map it to something like `super-q` or `F7`. Is there something wrong with my syntax? Neither works.

Comment: `(setq truncate-lines nil)` equals wrap.  `(setq truncate-lines t)` equals don't wrap.  You can make a function `(defun () "doc-string" (interactive) (message "This is my function))`.  You can make a keyboard shortcut . . . .  Have fun exploring the possibilities and enjoy your Emacs experience.  If you want to break words at word-boundaries at the window edge, then use `word-wrap t`

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying a few things. `(global-set-key (kbd "s-q") 'toggle-truncate-lines)` seems to work for toggling it, but I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: It is only those two variables -- `truncate-lines` and the optional `word-wrap`.  You may also enjoy using `M-x visual-line-mode` to toggle on and off.

Comment: FWIW, even more solutions are proposed for this problem at [this pre-e.s.c SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/q/299886/98270)

Answer (score 3):

A bit more manual per file but you can do do:

```
# -*- truncate-lines: nil -*-
```

At the top of the org-mode file.

Comment: This didn't work for me, which is a shame as I want to add this on a per-file basis. Is there something else I need to add to .emacs or somewhere to make this soft-wrap the lines?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid spelling mistakes you should try to use the `kbd` function for writing the keybinding.
My setting therefor looks like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x p") 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

because I use that keybinding globally (e.g. also in any prog-mode).
For your `org-mode-map` -only change it would look like this:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "s-p") 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

otherwise you will have to consider regular expression syntax.

Therefor see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-\\") 'next-line)
(global-set-key [?\C-x ?\C-\\] 'next-line)
(global-set-key [(control ?x) (control ?\\)] 'next-line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want soft-warp applied to all org files on permanent basis, just put the code below in your init file.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (toggle-truncate-lines nil) ))
```